# Black screen on bootup after removing ubuntu

Tags: linux

So I have been using ubuntu on my Lenovo legion y540 15irh for quite a while already and I've been hearing some great things about Pop os too. I decided to uninstall Ubuntu and install pop. Removing ubuntu went without any problems. I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/AWoEiyAufdY
To uninstall grub. After that I restarted my pc and now when I boot up it shows the Lenovo logo, then goes to a black screen which only says "restart system", and then it shuts itself off. How do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

In the video you linked, its about dual boot. If you do not have dual boot it would be much easier to just boot from the usb and perform the popOS install, and formatting the drive in the process. I could be missing something, let me know.

The process should look like:

- burn the popOS iso in a usb.
- insert it in the laptop.
- press ESC multiple times to get to the boot menu / boot order ( if this doesn't work enter the bios with the specific key for your laptop and change boot order to have the usb at the beginning)
- follow popOS install